# Convergence series proof

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $x_i\ge 0$ $\forall \ i\ge 1$. Show that $\sum x_i$ converges iff the series $\sum\frac{x_i}{1+x_i}$ converges.

I know how to show the forward part which is; since $\frac{x_i}{1+x_i}\le x_i$ thus by the comparison test if $\sum x_i$ converges so does $\sum\frac{x_i}{1+x_i}$.

Conversly is what I don't know how to do? If I let $\sum\frac{x_i}{1+x_i}$ converge then I know given an $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $k>i$ such that $\frac{x_i}{1+x_i} \to 0$ as $i\to \infty$ which implies that $\frac{x_i}{1+x_i}<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $\frac{x_i}{1+x_i}\rightarrow 0$, $x_i\rightarrow 0$.  Now use the limit comparison test.  $\frac{\frac{x_i}{1+x_i}}{x_i}=\frac{1}{1+x_i}\rightarrow 1$, so the two series agree.

Comment: Maybe I am thinking too much, because all I was thinking about was I have to show bound-ness. Never thought to use limit comparison, thanks!